# Eric - заблокировано меню Edit

Tags: python

Только начал работать с Python. В качестве IDE пытаюсь использовать Eric. Довольно мощная вещь. Однако, никак не могу разобраться с глупой проблемой: в главном меню Eric, при входе в меню Edit все элементы (за исключением двух субменю) заблокированы - показаны "серенькими".

Проблема именно в этом субменю. Остальные субменю активны и работают нормально. Когда я пытаюсь использовать кнопки на панели инструментов, которые реализуют отдельные пункты меню Edit (например: Закомментировать/Раскомментировать), то всё работает нормально.

Если меню Edit не использовать, то в остальном редактирование выполняется номально, файл сохраняется и всё такое прочее...

Скриншот экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Можете показать скриншот тот подменю?

Comment: @gil9read

>  Можете показать скриншот  

      Скриншот я сделал, но не могу разобраться, как его сюда загрузить :-( 
Почитав help попробовал нажимать Ctl/G - не помогает.

Comment: Если читать то, что написано в окошке, которое открывается при нажатии кнопочки "справка" в правом нижнем углу окошка ввода комментариев, то можно узнать очень много нового и совершенно бесполезного:-)  Почти ничего, из того, что там описано - не работает. Я даже не смог начать новый абзац, как не изгалялся... И там пробелы вставлял и сям и разрывы строк.. Никакого - эффекта!

Comment: В редакторе кликаете на пункт изображение (ctrl+g), появляется диалог и вставляете картинку: через ctrl+v если она в буфере обмена / или переносите файл с ней в диалог / или вставляете ссылку на картинку / или через диалог выбора файла выбираете ее

Comment: В каком редакторе? Редакторе комментариев?  Не вижу у него никаких **пунктов** :-(  Просто окно редактирования, справа от которого кнопка "Комментировать". Если нажать комбинацию Ctrl/G, то в окне статуса браузера появляется панель поиска текста на странице.

Comment: Может дело в браузере? Я использую FireFox...

Comment: Оказалось, что это надо делать не в комменте, а в сообщении :-)

Comment: Бывает.. в комментарии многое нельзя сделать. **Хотя бы** `простенькое` _форматирование_ *доступно*

Comment: @gil9red Сделал.